# Is there a way to get a 10% significance level in the results of Anova in R?

Tags: r, anova, significance

I need to use the aov (Anova) command in R to test for an interaction between two predictors in a data frame as follows:

```
av1<-aov(Index~Country*Period,cpi)
```

but I need the results at a 10% significance level (rather than the default of 5%). Is there a way to do this using the aov function in R?

Imagine the scenario of:

The Consumer Price Index (expressed as a percentage) is randomly sampled in Ireland, UK and France over Period 1 = {Jan – Apr}, Period 2 = {May – Aug} and Period 3 = (Sept – Dec}. Results are given below. It is of interest to know whether the Index varies by Country and by Period.

```
av1<-aov(Index~Country*Period,cpi)

# To produce the 2-way ANOVA table we use the function summary(…) in R

summary(av1)
```

The results from this Anova command uses a 5% significance level (according to the lecturer on our course).

Is there a way to get a significance level of 10%?

Any advice gratefully received!

This is the result at 5% (including a note from the Lecturer afterwards):

```
summary(av1)
                 Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
Country          3 3.669   1.2230 117.788  1.54e-07 ***
Period           2 0.053   0.0267 2.569    0.1310
Country:Period   3 0.121   0.0402 3.869    0.0498 *
Residuals        9 0.093   0.0104
---
Signif. codes: 0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Lecturer's question: Is there evidence of an interaction effect between the factors ‘Country’ and ‘Period’? Explain.

Lecturer's answer: The interaction effect between the factors ‘Country’ and ‘Period’ is marginally significant at 5% (p=0.049)

Comment: Just use the pvalues. You can choose any significance level you want.

Comment: Thanks Dason. It's nice to get a straightforward answer after being thoroughly befuddled by this lecturer! My confusion came about because in certain tests we've had to specify 0.95 in the functions (for example qf and qchisq).

My initial question seems a bit dumb in hindsight now but I wasn't sure whether variable interaction results would be affected by whether or not you entered a specific significance level.

Thanks again! Phil